# Can you video your facetime chat?

Tags: iphone

Is there anyway to record video of my facetime chats with my grandkids?

Comment: You CAN if you have a 3rd party software like Shou or another screen recorder

Comment: @Alex on the iPhone?

Comment: @patrix iOS 8 or lower I think, I have it on my phone Which is iOS 9.3.1

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately you can not do it. There is not way of recording unless you jailbreak.